# How to sanitize a collated column with text and numeric data to make it uniform for easy analysis in excel 2007

Tags: excel, collation, analysis, sanitization, vlookup

I have 3 column heads and I wanted to collate it with 3 similar heads from another sheets. 10%   at an average from each of the 6 columns is blank, I have to map the data based on these 3 columns to other data and I need them to be sanitized. So there are the blanks and then there are some cells which have text like 208110185726A570-14. Please help.

Comment: Just to be clear: are you wanting to remove the blanks entirely and then append the rows of one group of columns to the other group of columns? And does it matter if the data is a mix of numbers and text, or do you want them all the same format?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't heard back from the comment above, but I'll have a go at this anyway (and will be using assumptions that may be incorrect):

Given that you have included the tag [vlookup](/questions/tagged/vlookup), I'm assuming that you want to build a table that uses the leftmost column as an index of unique values to conduct a `VLOOKUP`. If that's the case, I don't see any way around blank cells in the leftmost columns in the two sheets, other than saying that the ensuing `VLOOKUP` would skip over any row that had a blank leftmost cell.

If you can live with that, the way I would go about it is pretty simple:

1. Copy the columns from one group (omitting the header row) and paste them to the end of other group. Again, since you have mentioned `VLOOKUP`, I'm assuming that keeping the cells in the rows next to each other is the goal (i.e. you can't remove the blanks in the columns because otherwise that would mess up the horizontal integrity of the cell relationships).
2. Do your `VLOOKUP`. Again, I'm assuming unique values in the leftmost column. This assumption is important, because it will make a difference to the decisions you make about what type of `VLOOKUP` you use (range vs. exact match) and what value is returned. For example, if you use exact match and there are repeating values, it will return the 1st match it finds.

Again, the assumptions might be wrong, but the question is a little unclear.